# Merging list of two objects to create a third object on the basis of common attribute

Tags: java, arraylist, merge, java-stream

I have two different csv files having data on two different entities and I have to merge two different csv files to create one on the basis of sql join type equijoin and left join.

so I have created first entity as class name Customer having attributes:

```
int CustomerId ;
String CustomerName;
int OrderId;
```

And List of object of this class like:

```
Customer c1 = new Customer(CustomerId, CustomerName, OrderId);
1 million objects..

List<Customer> cust = new ArrayList<>();
cust.add(c1);
cust.add(c2);
so on to make list of 1 million object.
```

Similarly, I have created class of second entity Order having attributes:

```
int orderId;
String orderName;
Date orderdate;

Order o1 = new Order(orderId, orderName, orderdate);
so on 1 million object
List<Oder> order = new ArrayList<>();
```

Now I need to merge both the object on the basis of orderId and generate third object having result class having all the attributes from both the classes described above.

Please suggest me solution using java stream 8 to map both the streams of list to create inner join and left join type example in the third new result class.

Comment: Any particular reason you use `List` and want to use streams?

Comment: Basically I want to read two different csv files having one column as having primary and foreign key relationship. and using java I want to process these two csv to create one csv using sql join either equi-join or left join depending upon the request to join two csv but the application should support both the join type. I started off with this logic to create list of object and thought of using java 8. please suggest me a better way if you know. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by sql? Do you want to use a database? You can use in memory `h2` you can load csv files directly into it and write from it.

Comment: There if=s no db involved by sql I meant to use analogy.. i.e. among the two files I want to create first files where I find a match between same column between two files.

Comment: and In the second files a kind of result what we get in left join where all the data from first file and null against the second file column values if that doest exist:

Comment: in first request my end result should be:
CustomerId customerName OrderId OrderName OrderDate
1              John             5             xyz            10 Sep 2017
there is a match on orderId between both the csv thats like equijoin. and likewise in case of left join:
CustomerId customerName OrderId OrderName OrderDate
1              John             null             null null

Comment: And are `customerId` and `orderId` unique?

Comment: yes they will be

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the getters, your `Customer` class should have the following method:

```
public boolean orderMatch(Order order) {
    //fixed the attribute name so it would be in camelCase
    return orderId == order.getId();
}
```

Of course, this implies that `Order` has a `getId()` getter method to get its `id` attribute.

Finally, you'll need a `CustomerExtended` class.

```
class CustomerExtended {
    int customerId ;
    String customerName;
    Order customerOrder;

    public CustomerExtended(Customer customer, Order order) {
        customerId = customer.getId();
        customerName = customer.getName();
        customerOrder = order;
    }
}
```

Now, you can create a `Function` which would search for the corresponding `Order` and append it to a `Customer`:

```
Function<Customer,CustomerExtended> extendCustomer = (c) ->{
    //I used the more descriptive name orderList instead of o1.
    Optional<Order> order = orderList.stream()
                                     .filter(c::orderMatch)
                                     .findFirst();
    if(order.isPresent()) {
        return new CustomerExtended(c,order.get());
    }
    return null;
};
```

And then you can apply it to the `Customer` list through a map.

```
List<CustomerExtended> newCustomerList = customerList.stream()
                                                     .map(c -> extendCustomer.apply(c))
                                                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**EDIT: A few last notes**

- There should be some check that the ID numbers are not duplicate either when adding the objects to the lists, or when the lists are populated.
- For semantic purposes, The `Customer` object as it is should be renamed `CustomerOrder` or be separated into an object only for customer info and an object which would store the relation between customer and order.
- The case where an order is not found should be better handled and throw an exception.